# concentration of sums of fourth moment of normals

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

I was wondering what is the best tail bound for 
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}\bigg\{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^4>(1+t)3n\bigg\}\le ?
\end{equation*}
where $X_k$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What counts as "best"?  The smallest tail bound is of course
$$
(2\pi)^{-n/2} \int_{\{(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) : \sum x_i^4 > (1+t)3n\} } e^{-\sum x_i^2 / 2} dx_1 \dotsb dx_n.
$$

Presumably you want something simpler.  Using standard concentration inequalities,
$$
\mathbb{P} \left\{ \|X\|_4 > \mathbb{E}\|X\|_4 + s \right\} \le e^{-s^2/2}
$$
where $\|X\|_4^4 = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^4$, and $\mathbb{E}\|X\|_4 \sim (3n)^{1/4}$.  It would take some fiddling to get the best constants, but assuming you're interested in large $t$, you would get an upper bound like $C \exp[-c\sqrt{(nt)}]$.

Comment: I need the results to hold for all t>0. Is there a result that applies in that setting?

Comment: @mohi: Sure, everything I wrote prior to the last sentence holds for all t.  You could also supplement the final bound I wrote (which would apply for $t > C$ with a simple Markov-type bound for smaller $t$.